# scroll-preserve-screen-position causes cursor to move forward one character at screen boundary

Tags: scrolling, cursor

I am using `(setq scroll-preserve-screen-position t)` as suggested at  https://superuser.com/a/184421/39697, and it works well, except for me, when I scroll at the top of the screen using `scroll-up-line`, the cursor moves foward one character (same with the bottom of the screen).

This isn't happening with `emacs -Q`, so I'm unsure what in my [configuration](https://github.com/asmeurer/dotfiles) is causing it. I'd like to use [bug-hunter](https://github.com/Malabarba/elisp-bug-hunter) to find why, but I'm unsure how to encode this as a test expression.

Comment: If a point is *partially* visible at the top or the bottom of the screen based on everything that is going on (e.g., font size, frame size, etc.), Emacs will (during redisplay) readjust to make it fully visible.  That is done at the C level, not `elisp`.  There are some additional settings that could make it more noticeable, and you might have added one of those -- e.g., `scroll-margin`.  I don't know if this is related to your issue.

Comment: Instead of just pointing us to your configuration, recursively bisect your init file to find the problem. It's very quick to do. You can use `comment-region` to comment out 1/2, then 3/4, 7/8,... of the file. Once you've located the problem, if you still need help then report about it here, in more detail.

Comment: Just to make sure, does this happen consistently? I mean: if you open any file that is longer than a single window, and you place point at the **last** line of the window, and you invoke `M-x scroll-up-line`, will it *always* move point forward by one character?

Comment: @Malabarba no it happens in the other direction. If I put it at the bottom line (and I am not at the top of the document) and I run `M-x scroll-down-line` then the cursor moves forward. For instance if the cursor is in column 3 after running `scroll-down-line` it will be in column 4 (and on the previous line obviously). Ditto for `scroll-up-line` if it is at the top of the windows: it moves one column forward each time.  It also happens when using `C-v` and `M-v`. I haven't been able to play with it too much yet, but it does seem to do it every time so far.

Comment: And to clarify, when the cursor is anywhere else in the window, or when scrolling it into the window (`scroll-up-line` when it's at the bottom of visa versa) the behavior is as expected: the cursor stays on the column it was on. This is also true of `C-v` and `M-v`: they only move the cursor column when it is at the very top or bottom of the window.

Comment: Sorry it took me a while to get back to you. The bug-hunter automated mode of operation uses batch mode, so it's not very good for doing things related to windows or frames. The good news is that the bug-hunter now has a fully interactive mode! Version 0.5 should be on Gelpa tomorrow, but you can also get it from github right now if you prefer.

Comment: [1] Invoke `M-x bug-hunter-init-file`, then answer `i` at the prompt (for interactive mode). [2] The bug hunter will start a separate Emacs frame. [3] On this new frame, evaluate `(setq scroll-preserve-screen-position t)` and then try to reproduce the problem. [4] After you close the frame, the bug hunter will ask you if you managed to reproduce the problem. [5] After repeating this several times, you should get a report.

Comment: Awesome. I install all my stuff with cask, so I'll wait for the release tomorrow.